# how to find out which of the following holds?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ : $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a given function.
 Consider the following statements:

$A$: The function $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

$B$: There exists a continuous function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f = g$ almost everywhere.

Which of the following implications are true?

a) $A\Rightarrow B$

b)  $B\Rightarrow A$

I have no idea how to look for this?

Comment: check definition, b is true. find an example show A is not true.

Comment: @runaround is it really so easy to check that A implies B? I mean if you restrict yourself to the points of continuity, you have to extend f somehow to the real line. B does not imply A. You could use the Dirichlet function (indicator function of th rationals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both implications are false.

1) suppose f is a.e. continuous. Take for example: $$f (x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$ Now suppose that we have $$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $$ and suppose $ g $ is continuous.  Then if $g=f$ a.e. we get a contradiction,  because $ g $ has to explode in zero and hence it cannot be continuous.

2) take $ f  = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ then $f=g$ a.e. but $ f $ has no points of continuity.